# UITableViewCell with UILabels selection not working properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a project that uses Storyboards. My custom UITableViewCells are difficult to select because of the labels on top of them. If I select a zone in which there is not a label the selection happens, otherwise is buggish (sometimes yes, sometimes no).

I think it depends on the fact that the labels prevent the cell selection. 
Is there an option in the IB that I should enable/disable to quickly solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that *User Interaction Enabled* is **not** ticked in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: Disabling the suggested flag on all the UITableViewCell's subviews worked! Thank you! :)